# display jquery fancybox as ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

I have:

- the `<a href>` link that displays a fancybox 
  and
- the `<form>`, that displays a message on the page when subtmit button clicked on ajax success. 
  They both work fine.

The code is below.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    { //this fancybox appears when <a href="..." ...>...</a> clicked
        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
            padding:15,
            closeBtn:true,
        });

        $("form#submit").submit(function ()
        {
            var name = $('#name').attr('value');
            var password = $('#password').attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"index/success",
                data:{ name:name, password:password},
                success:function ()
                {
                    //this form disappears and div appears when submit button of the <form id="submit" ...>...</form> clicked
                    $('form#submit').hide(function ()
                    {
                        $('div#errors').fadeIn(3000);

                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to move that fancybox to appear on ajax success. How should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call a fancybox manually with this simple function

```
$.fancybox(
        '<p>Content of the box in HTML</p>',
        {
                padding:15,
                closeBtn:true
        }
    );
```

Just add it to the success function.

Comment: Guys, thank you both. It's difficuilt to choose the best answer as both are perfect. Rob, sorry I choose this asnwer as the best, because it's shorter, better fits my needs. Thank you everybody!

Comment: No problem, we are here to help you out and not to collect as many points! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a link that is invisible to the end-user and trigger it with jQuery on the ajax success callback. Something like this:

```
<a id="hiddenlink" href="#fancy" style="display: none;"></a>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function ()
    { //this fancybox appears when <a href="..." ...>...</a> clicked
        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
            padding:15,
            closeBtn:true,
            }
        });

        $("form#submit").submit(function ()
        {
            var name = $('#name').attr('value');
            var password = $('#password').attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"index/success",
                data:{ name:name, password:password},
                success:function ()
                {
                    $("a#hiddenlink").trigger("click");
                    //this form disappears and div appears when submit button of the <form id="submit" ...>...</form> clicked
                    $('form#submit').hide(function ()
                    {
                        $('div#errors').fadeIn(3000);

                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: wow, it really works! Thank you! But, I mean... I want to "move" that lightnbox to ajax success, not to copy it. I mean I don't need that link on the page to trigger the lightbox, I need the lightbox ONLY on ajax success. Is that the best solution for the lightbox to trigger a link? Thank you.

Comment: This is one solution, you could also use the implementation in the answer below. You could also create a simple page and set the "href" key to the page you want to display, because i don't like to define the markup of the page inside my javascript and you can re-use the page on different locations